# Markov chain probability of reaching final state

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

Given a matrix with probability of moving from one state to another.

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0&0&0&1 \\ 4&0&0&3&2&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I have to calculate the probability of reaching state s3 s4 s5 from s0.
the answer to them are $3\over14$, $1\over7$, $9\over{14}$ respectively.

While my answers are s3, s4, s5 are $2\over9$, $1\over6$, $1\over9$.

Am I missing anything? 
Also How would I go with this when there are multiple paths?

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0&0&1&1 \\ 4&0&0&3&2&1 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If possible, show us your working so we can see what you've done. As far as I can see, the given answers are correct. 
Eg. $$P(S_3)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{4}{9}P(S_3)+\frac{1}{3}\right)$$
$$\implies P(S_3)=\frac{3}{14}$$

Comment: @Shuri2060 I missed something basic.
Can you please help me out in case of multiple, I have updated the question.

Comment: "Given a matrix with probability of moving from one state to another" Right, with probability $4$ for example, then?

Comment: @Did not sure on the actual name, but it's just a matrix which can have each element divided by its row sum to get the right-stochastic matrix. Perhaps 'Given a matrix where each element gives the number of ways of moving from one state to another' could be a suggested edit?

Comment: As I explained to the last person who asked about this in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2337832/265466), you’re not going to get very far with standard Markov matrix techniques unless you first convert this into a proper stochastic matrix. The answer to that question gives both a specific solution for the first matrix and a general way to solve these problems.

Comment: Also, you should show your work instead making people guess where you might have gone wrong in your calculations.

Comment: AMN: Did you open a new account to repost this?

Comment: nope, I did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment -

Explanation of the matrix:

If you index the matrix starting from $0$, then the element at $M_{ij}$ gives the number of ways of getting from state $S_i$ to $S_j$.

Take the second row, $i=1$, which is $[4,0,0,3,2,0]$, for example. This tells us that there are $4$ ways of getting to $S_0$, $3$ to $S_3$ and $2$ to $S_4$.

The probability of $A$ given $B$ is

$$P(A|B)={\textrm{the number of ways of getting to $A$ from $B$}\over\textrm{the total number of ways of getting anywhere from $B$}}$$

The probabilities you get, therefore, are $P(S_0|S_1)=\frac{4}{9}$, $P(S_3|S_1)=\frac{1}{3}$, $P(S_4|S_1)=\frac{2}{9}$.

---

With a general matrix, $M$, let the probability of eventually reaching state $b$ from state $a$ be written as $P(S_a \rightarrow S_b)$.

Then

$$P(S_a \rightarrow S_b)=\sum_i P(S_i|S_a)P(S_i \rightarrow S_b)$$

Using this, you can iteratively calculate the probabilities (this would get harder to do with more complicated matrices).

---

Example calculation:

Say you want to know $P(S_0 \rightarrow S_3)$.

The only way of getting to $S_3$ is from $S_1$. If you land back at $S_0$ from $S_1$, you're back where the original problem started. Landing in states 2, 4 and 5 would get you trapped, so $P(S_{2,4,5} \rightarrow S_3)=0$. Hence you get:

$$P(S_0 \rightarrow S_3)=P(S_1|S_0)\left(P(S_0|S_1)P(S_0 \rightarrow S_3)+P(S_3|S_1)\right)$$

which gives the numbers I provided in the comment.

Comment: I got the first part. thanks for that.
But how will calculation be done for 2nd part when there are multiple paths P(S0→S5)
and these are the states that they have traveled 1,1,1 in row 1 means each have a probability of 1/3.

Comment: I might sound dumb. But I am very new to it and solving some problem which is linked to this.

Comment: @AmanSeth You use $P(S_a \rightarrow S_b)=\sum_i P(S_i|S_a)P(S_i \rightarrow S_b)$. So, eg, consider $P(S_0 \rightarrow S_5)$ for the 2nd matrix. You get $P(S_0 \rightarrow S_5)=P(S_1|S_0)(P(S_0 \rightarrow S_5)+P(S_5|S_1))+P(S_5|S_0)$. You can ignore the other terms, as $P(S_3 \rightarrow S_5)=0$, for example.